# NSTask missing in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, shell, nstask

I seems to be unable to use NSTask in iOS. Did anyone else experienced that issue?

So I have a simple file:

```
import Foundation
var task = NSTask()
```

And I am getting:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTask'
```

Anyone experiencing similar or same issue? If so, any alternatives to shell out other then NSTask?

Thank you.

Comment: `NSTask` is not available for iOS.

Comment: Right, well that is quite an important information to have! :) thx